# GoLang Gin - Binding JSON data from POST request rewrites all Identifier Fields to 0

Tags: json, api, go, post, go-gin

I am taking my first steps with GoLang, and currently setting up an API Server, which is able to read JSON file from POST Request and save that to Memory.

I have a JSON File as Following:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "kubernetes",
        "uri": "https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "jenkins",
        "uri": "https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins"
    }
]
```

Which I am POST:ing to the API Server running on local port.

Here is my setupRoutes() - function:

```
func setupRoutes() {

    // Initialize Router
    router := gin.Default()

    // Initialize Routes
    router.GET("/api/projects", getProjects)
    router.GET("/api/projects/:id", getProjectByIdentifier)
    router.POST("/api/projects", uploadProjects)        

    // Start the Router
    router.Run("localhost:8080")
}
```

and here is my uploadProjects() - function:

```
// Reads file from POST request, and saves that to Memory.
func uploadProjects(c *gin.Context) {

    // Initialize Object
    var obj []Project

    // Bind JSON Data to Object
    c.BindJSON(&obj)

    fmt.Println(obj) // For Testing: What is binded.

    // Save Data to Memory
    proj = obj
```

}

and here is the Project Struct:

```
type Project struct {
    Identifier int64    `json: id`
    Name string         `json: name`
    Uri string          `json: uri`
}
```

After executing this - I can print that data out right away, what is being binded or I can fetch that with my GET /api/projects - call, and the result is always:

```
[{0 kubernetes https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes} {0 jenkins https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins}]
```

What I've tried:

- I've tried to swap between string, int and int64 types of Identifier Field in my struct.
- Googled a Bunch

This is probably something very simple, but I don't really know where to look at this point, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` field does not match the field name `Identifier`.  Fix by using properly formatted JSON field tags.  The field tags used in the question are not recognized by the JSON codec.

```
type Project struct {
    Identifier int64    `json:"id"`
    Name string         `json:"name"`
    Uri string          `json:"uri"`
}
```

Comment: It was, in fact, something very simple, got it working now. Thank you! :)